# The method addExtensions(File[]) in the type ChromeOptions is not applicable for the arguments (File)

Tags: file, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate chrome extension using WebDriver. My code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addExtensions(new File("/Data/mycrx.crx"));
}
```

It is showing an error:

> "The method `addExtensions(File[])` in the type `ChromeOptions` is not applicable for the arguments (`File`)"

I searched on Google and at every location it says the above code should work.

Can you please let me know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addExtensions` expects a `File` array (hence the `[]`) and you pass a single `File` object. To *hack* (fix) it try running:

```
options.addExtensions(new File[]{(new File("/Data/mycrx.crx"))});
```